# MatLab colorbar can't see the right scale

Tags: matlab, data-visualization, matlab-figure, colorbar

I'm doing numerics and I have an error plot made on two parameters, which means that I have a matrix where in the (i,j)-component I have the error made using two different specific values for the two parameters.

I used `imagesc` command in MatLab to obtain the following result:

[image]

**The problem is with the colorbar**: my values ranges from 1 to 10^(-16), so I need to do a *logarithmic colorbar* in order to see a right scaling in the "blue" part of the plot, since the values there can change of some orders of magnitude. Actually, I found lots of questions and answers, and I chose this one from  [MatLab community](https://it.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/100066-how-do-i-create-a-logarithmic-scale-colormap-or-colorbar)

So I substitute the parameter "L" in the linked code with 
`L = [1e-16,1e-15,1e-14,1e-13,1e-12,1e-11,1e-10, 1e-9, 1e-8, 1e-7, 1e-6,1e-5,1e-4,1e-3,1e-2,1e-1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5,0.6,0.7,0.8,0.9,1e0];`

but what I obtain is the following:

[image]

and so **now I can't see the changes in the upper triangular part** of the table.

Does anyone has some idea on how to fix it in order to see better the changes in the yellow part?

**EDIT**:

[image]

Comment: You are making a *logarithmic* scale from `1e-16` to `1e-1` (0.1), and then make a *linear* scale from 0.1 to 1. In other words, you are mixing log and linear scales. What your code does now is to take a logarithmic scale, with linear tickmarks within the yellow region. Just don't mix scales I'd say. Make one plot for the lower triangle with log scale, and a plot with linear scale for the upper triangle plot.

Comment: @Adriaan Yeah, that is what I was thinking when I was writing the question, but I wasn't sure! Do you know by chance if there's a way to have everything in one plot?

Comment: I'd put these two side by side, and clearly mention the difference in colour scale in the caption. You can put the two into the same figure (make the other half `nan`, plot over one another), but that'd be bad IMO. You can't easily discern between the two scales then, leading to possibly wrong conclusion made. I'd simply make two subplots, and for extra clarity use different colour maps.

Comment: It is not very reasonable to include a half-linear half-log colorbar. Even worse, even if you merge the top yellow with the bottom blue, the image would be confusing and hard to interpret. Like @Adriaan suggested, I would use two separate plots. Also use `set(gca,'ColorScale','log')` for the log part (instead of defining `L`). That is a lot easier!

Comment: @RealReza
I'm using your suggestion doing two separate plots, but it does not detect values less than 1e-4. I mean, I can't see the right tonalities of blue in the lower part. Do you know how I can fix this?

Comment: Let's say your matrix is called `im` . Do this: `figure; subplot(121); imagesc(im); colorbar` for the yellow zone to have a linear scale. Then, `subplot(122); imagesc(im); colorbar; set(gca, 'ColorScale', 'log');` for the logarithmic blue zone. If the scale is not as you wish on the log plot, you may adjust it using `colorbar('Limits', [1e-13 1])`.

Comment: Thanks, it's almost what I did and I'm almost done, but I have still the problem that my "logarithmic" colorbar does not detect the different scales in the blue zone. I edited the answer with the result

Comment: The colorbar limits have not been applied to the log plot. Have you done this: `subplot(122); colorbar('Limits', [1e-13 1])` ?